# Sending XML fails

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to send XML to a remote site. I originally coded it using curl. That failed (no response) and the rep for the company said it was because I was using curl. So I changed the code to not use it but it fails with

> file_get_contents(https://testws.atdconnect.com/ws/3_4/locations.wsdl/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

The code I am using is shown below. The first call tries to send with curl while the second doesn't. Can someone point out where I am going wrong, please?

```
    $client_id = "the id";
    $username = "the user";
    $password = "the pass";
    $url = "https://testws.atdconnect.com/ws/3_4/locations.wsdl/";

    echo GetDistributionCenter($url, $client_id, $username, $password);
    echo GetDistributionCenter($url, $client_id, $username, $password, true);

    function GetDistributionCenter($url, $client_id, $username, $password, $send_array = false) {
       $xml_str = '
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/locations">
         <soapenv:Header>
           <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:UsernameToken atd:clientId="' . $client_id . '" xmlns:atd="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd">
              <wsse:Username>' . $username . '</wsse:Username> 
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' . $password . '</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
           </wsse:Security>
         </soapenv:Header>
         <soapenv:Body>
           <loc:getDistributionCenterRequest>
              <loc:servicingDC>070</loc:servicingDC>
           </loc:getDistributionCenterRequest>
         </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';

       if ($send_array) {
          $xml_str = array($xml_str);
          $xml_str = http_build_query($xml_str);
          return  SendPostRequest($url, $xml_str);
       }   

       return SendXMLCommand($url, $xml_str);
    } 

    function SendPostRequest($url, $postdata) {
       $opts = array('http' =>
           array(
               'method'  => 'POST',
               'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata) . "\r\n",
               'content' => $postdata
           )
       );
       $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
       return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    }

    function SendXMLCommand($url, $parsed_data) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5; 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parsed_data);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);  
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($data))); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            $result = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Is there definitely supposed to be a `/` at the end of the WSDL address? Because it works without it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're writing your own SOAP request/response layer instead of using the native [SoapClient](http://php.net/SoapClient)?

Comment: The ending / is in their example. I tried removing it but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I feel fairly confident in php but never coded in xml before so I'm just using examples I've found. The class looks interesting but it doesn't show how to add the xml data so I'm reluctant to take a wrong turn and dig a deeper hole.

Comment: I noticed that the curl code has a strlen for $data, which doesn't exist. i changed it to $parsed_data and the script timed out.

Comment: Just an update in case someone has this problem. The reason for the failure was the line feed with the $xml_str = ' line. I removed that and the code worked. My thanks to those that tried to help.